# Chrome blocks clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard

I am using Javascript to copy text from the clipboard and it works using the below code

```
const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();

return text
```

However Chrome shows the following prompt:

[image: prompt]

Is there a way I can allow clipboard pasting using Chrome options or if I can add my website as a trusted source?

Comment: @KieranQuinn That's for writing to the clipboard, not reading it.

Comment: I highly suspect that any way to read the user's clipboard while bypassing the permissions prompt would be considered a security vulnerability in Chrome, which  I doubt we would be allowed to post here should it exist, and if we did it would be rapidly patched. If you're developing a website for your organization's internal use you may be able to look at chrome policies: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289